# NNJoin plugin crash

Tags: qgis, distance, debugging

I'm trying to run *NNjoin* plugin to compute nearest distance between my plot and buildings (urban) but I'm having this error :

Here are my [files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/rwmc5sdr0svqkpo,ieh5d39relrmorz/shared) (maybe not projected yet but it should be in ESPG 23839)

[image]

> ### Report Details
>
> **Python Stack Trace** ``` Windows fatal exception: access violation
>
> Current thread 0x000067a8 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users/germa/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\nnjoin/python/plugins\NNJoin\NNJoin_plugin.py",
> line 177 in run
> self.dlg.exec_() ```
>
> **Stack Trace**
>
> ````
> QgsCustomization::preNotify : QObject::event :
> QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper : QApplication::notify :
> QgsApplication::notify : QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
> QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents : qt_plugin_query_metadata :
> QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents : qt_plugin_query_metadata :
> QEventLoop::exec : QDialog::exec : PyInit_QtWidgets :
> PyArg_ParseTuple_SizeT : PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
> PyFunction_Vectorcall : PyFloat_FromDouble : PyVectorcall_Call :
> PyObject_Call : PyInit_QtCore : PyInit_QtCore : PyInit_QtCore :
> PyInit_QtCore : QObject::qt_static_metacall : QAction::activate :
> QAbstractButton::click : QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
> QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent : QWidget::event :
> QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper : QApplication::notify :
> QgsApplication::notify : QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
> QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent : QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
> QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy : QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
> QApplication::notify : QgsApplication::notify :
> QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
> QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
> QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
> QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents : qt_plugin_query_metadata :
> QEventLoop::exec : QCoreApplication::exec : main : BaseThreadInitThunk
> : RtlUserThreadStart : ```
>
>
>
> **QGIS Info** QGIS Version: 3.34.0-Prizren QGIS code revision: ffbdd67881 Compiled against Qt: 5.15.3 Running against Qt: 5.15.3
> Compiled against GDAL: 3.7.2 Running against GDAL: 3.7.2
>
>
>
> **System Info** CPU Type: x86_64 Kernel Type: winnt Kernel Version: 10.0.22621
> ````

Comment: Just tested your data, and everything works fine on my Windows 11 with QGIS 3.28.10-Firenze and NNJoin 3.1.3.

Comment: Maybe try with a new profile? Otherwise open a ticket via : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug&projects=&template=10_bug_report.yml

Comment: I did a little testing on my Win10 machine.  The crash did not occur at the 3.28.x level. However, it did occur at the 3.34.x level.  I also created a new profile at 3.34.2, and the crash occurred.  So the crash may have something to do with the 3.28 to 3.34 transition.  The plugin has not been updated since 2019, and its author has not been seen on SE-GIS in over two years.